# Firebug shows error "_11 is undefined"

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

Actually that's it. What does this error mean? I've googled on it, but found nothing.
This error appears in firebug console after the page is loaded, or when i click on tabs. It does not prevent the execution of another JavaScript code, but the nature of it is mysterious for me.

Comment: Show us an example - It's probably a bug in some JavaScript code.

Comment: Click on error message, it should send you to the file/line where the error is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere in your code or the JS framework you use, a variable pointer _11 is called but nothing is assigned to it. Hence javascript gives undefined.

It sound indeed, like mmattax says, as a minified javascript variable name. It probalby references a variable in your javascript that is not defined.

Answer (score 3):

"_11" sounds like a JavaScript variable or function that has been minimized.